# Proper way of running long sync task in python asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a setup where I pass messages asynchronously, but I also have some heavy workload running tasks (up to minutes). I can't wrap my head around how I should do that with asyncio. For example, what I want to achieve:

- long running async function
- receive a message
- do heavy computation
- send the result

Currently, I am doing the heavy computation in the asyncio loop, but this blocks the communication.

How can I start a heavy sync computation? Some code:

```py
def heavy(i: num) -> num:
  result = ...
  return result

async def main():
  while True:
    req = await getInput()
  
    result = ??? heavy(req.num)

    await sendResult()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should not execute long-running tasks in an asyncio event loop thread, for exactly the reason you described: it occupies the thread for the duration, or at least until the task `await`s some event.  You would ordinarily want to run such work in a separate thread.

Either [run_coroutine_threadsafe()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) or [loop.call_soon_threadsafe()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) can help you do that, depending on whether you want to use a Future or a callback to find out about the completion and results of the heavy task.

With that said, it's not clear from your description of the program how the messaging is really supposed to work, or how it makes sense to use asyncio for your purposes.  You should consider the possibility that it is the wrong tool for your job.

Comment: Might also be worth multiprocessing to avoid slowdowns due to the GIL. Multiprocessing could also be really useful depending on if the heavy task uses a lot of memory, as that will allow memory to be freed after the operation completes.